# multiple time series using ts () function wrong data

Tags: time-series, read-data

i have a monthly time series data containing 528 rows and i use ts()function as follows

**oilfulldata <- ts(data$logOil, start = c(1976,01), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12 )**

this function is working proberly and i get the values stored in oilfulldata as i see them in the excel sheet i import the data from

> head(Oilfulldata)
> [1] 1.080266 1.082785 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291

second
i try to make multiple time series from different dates as follows

Oildata1 <- ts(data$logOil, start = c(1976,01), end = c(1999,12), frequency = 12 )

Oildata2 <- ts(data$logOil, start = c(2002,01), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12 )

first code also is also working proberly and get the values like i see them in the excel sheet i import the data from

> head(Oildata1)
> [1] 1.080266 1.082785 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291

second code is my problem
although i get no error but stored data is worng

> head(Oildata2)
> [1] 1.080266 1.082785 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291 1.085291

stored data shows the data from 1976,01 although i specified another start date

can anyone tell me whats going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `window()` function:

```
Oildata1 <- window(oilfulldata, start = c(1976,01), end = c(1999,12))
Oildata2 <- window(oilfulldata, start = c(2002,01), end = c(2019,12))
```

The `ts()` function is just grabbing enough observations from the start of the `data$logOil` vector to match the `start`, `end` and `frequency` arguments. It has no way of knowing what time periods the observations correspond to.